# Associate Multiple Mobile Apps with one Facebook Page

Tags: ios, facebook

When you create a mobile app in facebook it allows you to associate it with a facebook page. I would like to be able to associate all of my mobile apps with a single Facebook Page. On first glance this doesn't seem possible. Does everyone create a new facebook page for each mobile app or is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is one 'App Page' per App ID - there's no way to have multiple apps represented by a single app page.